# map of 2 unique_ptr's

Tags: c++, dictionary, std, unique-ptr, stdmap

I have a couple of questions about using `unique_ptr` in a container. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
class Stuff
{
public: 
    std::map<std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<int> > GetInfo() {return m_mapInfo;}

    // Is this bad??
    std::map<std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<int> > MoveInfo() {return std::move(m_mapInfo);}

private:    
    std::map<std::unique_ptr<int>, unique_ptr<int> > m_mapInfo;
};
```

This does not compile. It gives me the error C2248. I'm using VS2012.

Now I'm not using `unique_ptr`s of `int`s; they're actually `unique_ptr`s to abstract base classes, but I wanted to remove any issues of whether the error was down to my copy/move constructors/assignment operators.

Can anyone explain the error, and how to fix it?

Second, is my `MoveInfo()` function bad practice? It could only be called once for each Stuff object, as the map member would be empty after it, yes?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, what `C2248` actually says.

Comment: `m_mapInfo` is not copyable, so `GetInfo` is wrong, do you want to return reference instead ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: [C2248](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsbce2bh.aspx) is for error with visibility.

Comment: Using a `unique_ptr<int>` as the key seems kind of odd.

Comment: @Jarod42 I've posted this comment as an incentive for the OP to edit their question and put the verbatim error messages there.

Answer (score 1):

`unique_ptr` are designed to take and keep ownership of a pointer, i.e. to be unique. This is why they are not [copiable](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr/).

Returning a copy to a map would mean to duplicate (copy) all its content which is not possible due to the unique_ptr.  This is why you get the [C2248](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsbce2bh.aspx) message.

Either return a reference to the map, or consider using [`shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/?kw=shared_ptr) (so that several maps can share a reference to the same pointer).

Comment: But the OP `move`d the map. Where is the copy?

Comment: @nwp OP has a function GetInfo() which returns the map by value, which means copy it.